# Is there any way to get the key value in a map for a single object in the map in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart

I've searched a lot but could not find a case where one can retrieve the value of the key for a Map object. My use case involves retrieving data as a json from Http, decoding it to a map, then getting the data from the map, including the keys, and store it as an object. Most cases here talk about retrieving all the keys, which I don't want. My json structure is as follows, FWIW:

```
DB
|__jobs
    |___key1
          |____title
          |____company
          |____salary
```

Comment: I don't think I get your problem correctly, do you want to get the value of key1 from a Map object? in that case you could of course do something like this:  jobs["key1"]

Comment: Please read the subject under json serialization and deserialization: @JsonSerializable()
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: @KhashayarMotarjemi, I could do that, but I don't want to pick a single specific key, but rather do it for multiple other key-value pairs, one-by-one. Thank you for your help btw.

Comment: @IsraelKouperman, I figured it out. Basically I've revised my factory to take in the jsonKey as a parameter too. Kind of silly of me tbh, but posting for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to change my factory in my classes so that I can pass the key as a parameter:

```
  factory Job.fromJson(String jobID, Map<String,dynamic> json) {
    return Job(
        uid: jobID,
    );
  }
```

And in my decode function:

```
    map.forEach((jobsID, jobsData) {
      _jobsList.add(Job.fromJson(jobsID, jobsData));
    });
```

I haven't tested whether it will cause issues in future though.

Comment: I suggest you also check out map method of Iterable class: [map](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/map.html)